# Check Adobe Air SQLite Db for corruption

Tags: apache-flex, sqlite, air, adobe, corruption

I have an Adobe Air SQLite db in my application.  I was wondering if there was anyway for me to test for corruption provided the db opens ?  PRAGMA statements aren't allowed, so that is out of the question.

Answer (score 0):

[PRAGMA integrity_check](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_integrity_check) is the only reasonable method.

You could try to read all data from the DB, but this will not find all errors.